# Why change from focus() to trigger('focus')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was going through the history of dropdown.js in bootstrap and came across the following change History file on git, [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/8a78bc065f866763607f104907b7a2ac9fa6ceec):

```js
$this.focus()   // focus() being changed to trigger('focus');
$this.trigger('focus')
```

Now, the guy here has left a comment about the change saying:

> Makes life for people with custom jQuery builds excluding event
>   aliases much easier.

I don't quite understand what's the difference here between using `focus()` or `trigger('focus')`, as for me both have the same effect; why has the author chosen such a change?

Comment: huh , why the downvote ??

Comment: i am here to spead love nd upvotes ... and brotherhood , haters gonna hate .

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules.

If you are making a custom jQuery build and exclude `event/alias` module - you won't have shortcuts to events (e.g. `.click()`, `.focus()`, `.ready()`, etc).

So you'll have to use `.on('eventName', handler)` for event binding and consequently `.trigger('eventName')` to trigger jQuery event.

Comment: ! thanks my bro from RUSSIA :) , i am from russia too .

Answer (score 3):

People with custom jQuery builds could create or modify their own `focus()` functions intended to do whatever they want. Imagine if you create your own `focus()` which allows lot of parameters and chains multiple callback; it would be a mess when you combine its usage with the jQuery `focus()` basic function.

When you use a trigger it's qute obvious you're going to *trigger* an action; in this case, to focus an element.

Beside of that, using the `trigger()` functions makes the code a little easier to understand.